# Meteor increase size of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a running Meteor project and wanted to test, if it scales.
So in fact I have to save data in a collection where one document uses round about 500 KB. At 682 entries (documents) in this collection Meteor exits with code 3.

[image: This is how it looks like in console.]

I heard about a maximum of 32MB data, why is that? How can I get more space? Will more space have impacts on efficiency?
I need about 10000 entries of 500 KB. Is that even possible?
Would appreciate answers and also solutions (like maybe outsource mongodb?).

Comment: it's per document, And it's huge you probably won't hit any limits ever. The problem must be something else... Maybe you don't have enough RAM

Comment: Okay, I develop on my gaming computer. I have 32 GB RAM, 32 MB should not be a problem ;) Maybe Meteor limits itself the RAM it can use?

Comment: any other errors just exited with code 3?

Comment: no this is the first time and if i drop the collections via meteor-mongo console, the application starts again. I reproduce the error every time I try to add the 682'th entry.

Comment: weird can you try this with `meteorpad.com`? and share the link with the code this way I can help

Comment: I think my project is too big to give u a meteorpad.com version of it. I found out that if I generate more than 682 entries it crashes on runtime (exit code 3 always). If I generate 450 entries it crashes not on runtime, but if I restart my app. If I generate 250 entries it works. If I split my data in multiple collections, it also crashes.

Comment: I run a meteor database containing tens of millions of entries and it doesn't do this  There must be something else going on, unless it's some restriction with windows

Comment: Because I'm developing on Windows, I can only work with a 32bit database, which is limited to 2GB of data. 64 bit databases are unlimited. If you develop under Linux, is this a 64bit database?